# ColorBox error in IE "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, colorbox

I am trying to add a jquery colorbox to my webpage using the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function ()
        {
            $(".popup")
            .colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:695, innerHeight:340, overlayClose:false });

        })
    </script>
    <a class='popup' href='http://www.bbc.co.uk'>bbc.co.uk</a>
</body>
```

It works for both firefox and chrome. But when I run it in IE7 I get the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Are the JavaScript files loaded correctly?

Comment: Yeah all javascript files have loaded correctly

Comment: What version of jquery are you loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you have a `<script>` tag that is invalid or that contains a type attribute set to something other than `text/javascript`.

Without seeing that part of the code, we can't figure out exactly what is wrong.

**More information**

Script tags must have a closing `</script>`. `<script />` will not work in all browsers.

Additionally, the `type` attribute must either be `text/javascript` or not present. If it is `application/javascript` some versions of IE will not execute it.

Comment: All my <script> tag have the correct type text/javascript and all have closing tags </script>

Comment: are any of the other tags around it invalid? There's no reason for one browser to be choking on this if it isn't tag related. It isn't going to be a javascript error unless there are more errors happening that you aren't informing us of.

Comment: I quickly made a blank webpage just with the popup and still have the problem with ie

Comment: Can you post the source of it to somewhere that we can see it such as jsfiddle.com?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9XJAG/2/ however i had to include the css and js directly due to mimetype mismatches. Is your server returning the files with the correct mimetype?

Comment: I must have had a corrupted version of the colorbox javascript file. As I just used yours and it has worked. Thank you so much for you help